# How can I make my Eclipse RCP app's keyboard shortcuts (accelerators) work immediately after startup?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Our Eclipse RCP application was originally built in the 3.1/3.2 era and was running on 3.2 until we switched to 3.6 recently.  Its `IApplication` runs via `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(...)`.  The `WorkbenchAdvisor` we pass to that function overrides`createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(...)` to return a `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` whose `createActionBarAdvisor(...)` returns an `ActionBarAdvisor`.

This `ActionBarAdvisor`'s `makeActions(...)` creates and `register()`s a bunch of `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action`s, many of which do things like `setAccelerator(SWT.CTRL | 'O');` in their constructors.  The `Action`s are subsequently installed in the `ActionBarAdvisor`'s `fillMenuBar(...)` and `fillCoolBar(...)` methods.

The problem we are having (now that we are on Eclipse RCP 3.6) is that these accelerators don't seem to be active until their menus are shown (even if no action is taken besides closing the menu again).

We see [a relevant bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243758) but are having some difficulty understanding how to apply its remedy to our situation.  We recognize that instead of `Action`s we "ought" to be using commands, handlers, and key bindings.  But we're hoping we don't have to go down that path just yet.

How can we make our accelerators "live" as soon as the application starts up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting around and experimenting a bit trying to apply the advice from [the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243758), we added the following to our `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`, which seems to have done the trick:

```
@Override
public void postWindowCreate() {
    getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getMenuManager().updateAll(true);
}
```

We have no idea how well this fits with the Workbench's design expectations; there could be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't choose to use o.e.ui.bindings extension point, then there isn't a better way. You should only force update the menuManager yourself as you have done in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Prakash mentioned, if you want to keep down that path in your RCP app you must render all of the main menus to see your accelerators.

There is a partial upgrade path that will get you on the right track to commands without forcing a complete switch over right away.  For each action in your menu, define a command with an id and define a binding to the shortcut you want in your plugin.xml.  Then,  when you create the action in your ActionBarAdvisor, don't set the accelerator.  Set the IAction.setActionDefinitionId(*) to the command id, can call register(action);

Then you no longer need to use menuManager.updateAll(true) to eagerly render all of your main menu.